# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Raspberry Pi's [first moderator election](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: goldilocks] [image: Ghanima] [image: Steve Robillard]

They'll be installed [as elected moderators](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering. Also, please share your assistance and advice with Ghanima as they learn the ropes!

Join me in thanking Jivings for their contributions as *pro tempore* moderator during the beta period.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6511194454097920/0).

Comment: @jivings, you should take a great deal of pride in leading the community to this milestone.

Comment: Congratulations to all.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks Jon and Steve :)

Comment: Congrats on becoming our new mods, Steve, Ghanima and goldilocks. Thanks a lot to Jivings for bringing our community to where it is, and good luck for the future. Finally I would like to say good work to Jacob for nominating themselves and keep trying in future! We appreciate all of your hard work too.